# Why is Neo4J slow over HTTPS?

Tags: https, neo4j

Why would Neo4J be slow to respond over HTTPS compared to HTTP?

I have the same database configured to run with both protocols. The same query takes well under 1,000ms when using the HTTP endpoint, but over 30,000ms on the HTTPS endpoint. In addition, just loading the Neo4J browser is taking a lot longer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Neo4J devs, there was a Jetty (the embedded web server) bug in the version of Neo4J I am using, 2.2.6. Version 2.3.7 seems to perform as expected in my limited testing, but I could not test with my actual data for other reasons.